# PHP query, get rows from last 24 hours

Tags: php

I am trying to make a report that shows all the loans made in the last day. The time is saved as a time stamp in the database onloan and is saved in the format yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00. The code I have so far is shown below but i cannot get the time formatted correctly and -1 day.

```
$yday  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")-1, date("Y"));
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM onloan
          WHERE (time > $yday)";
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM onloan
WHERE DATE(Time) = DATE(CAST(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS DATE))
```

Answer (score 8):

You want to use `strtotime()`.

Try `$yday = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("-1 day"))`

Comment: thanks this is showing the time correctly formatted although the query will not execute, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
select * from onloan where date(time)=date(date_sub(now(),interval 1 day));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easier SQL way of doing it.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM onloan WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),time) <= 1";
```